# Add attribute value from a Point layer to a Line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have extracted nodes from a line shapefile.
On these nodes, I have extracted altitude values from a raster DEM using SAGA 'Add raster value to point'.

I want now to make the inverse of the first operation, i.e. getting the original lines again, but with the new altitude on each of their points (so stored in the `geom`).
I obviously can't make a join on attributes. And a union doesn't keep the fields of the points.

How would you do that, if it's possible?

Comment: Join attributes by location. Also, why can't you join on attributes? Usually there's an option to create nodes with the polylines id.

Comment: Yes I've got the following error:    `Algorithm Join attributes by location starting...    

5L See log for more details`

Comment: Did you extracted the nodes with `Extract nodes` tool? If so the id from lines and nodes are the same, so you can join them by their attributes. If you want to make some kind of pre-processing then you should export as table and process it, like grouping same id nodes using the average elevation. Then add the table and join with the lines layer.

Comment: That's the point, I need exact Z value for each node of the lines. So it's only possible in the `geom`, AFAIK.

Comment: But how do you want to join the attribute in the line feature? There will be at least two nodes for each line, you want to get a mean value from those nodes or what?

Comment: Indeed, as I said, I do not want to `join` because it's a nonsense. What I wish is to have 3D lines. AFAIK we can't project 2D lines to a TIN or a raster DEM to retrieve a Z values for each node of the line. So I operated by splitting the lines into points with which it's now possible to project on a raster DEM to retrieve the Z value.

Comment: AFAIK polyline shapefile specification alone does not allow such data structure, for that I usually construct a graph/network. I'm not familiar though with this in qgis, I usually go for Postgis.

Comment: The best you can achieve is to explode the lines and create two fields, one will contain the from_z and another one to_z.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not misreading, overall goal is getting `3D Line Shapefile` derived from the DEM.

Then GRASS `v.drape` may be one of alternative approach, which has become accessible through *QGIS Processing Toolbox*.

[image]